# App 2sxc v16.1 throw an unexpected error in Oqtane 3.4.3

Tags: 2sxc

We try to install 2sxc v16.1 with Oqtane 3.4.3 in a production environment. The server is a new Windows Server 2022 with SQL Server 2022. We use the checklist https://azing.org/2sxc/r/fOG3aByY to install. (2) Download and Accept is working. (3) Click Install is not possible. Nevertheless the module is installed and we added it to a page. The result is an error "An Unexpected Error Has Occurred" on the page. The message in the log "An Unexpected Error Has Occurred In ToSic.Sxc.Oqt.App, ToSic.Sxc.Oqtane.Client: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". The exception Description from the log: "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at ToSic.Sxc.Oqt.App.Index.OnParametersSetAsync() in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Oqtane\ToSic.Sxc.Oqt.Client\App\Index.razor.cs:line 64
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)"

We try uninstall 2sxc and reinstall. No effect. Are this versions not compatible?

Comment: According to https://go.2sxc.org/oqtane-install it's compatible and should just work. If you're having difficulties, just reach out to us ;) we'd love to help.

Comment: We just spent some time to reproduce it and we can't - everything seems to work.  My guess is that you have some security settings which don't allow 2sxc to write some files - so it can't register that installation was complete or something.

Comment: Note: we did find an issue with 2sxc/Oqtane + OAuth. That will be fixed in 16.02

Comment: We fixed the OAuth bug which may be what you ran into. But the latest release will require Oqtane 4.

Comment: The next step: We install Oqtane 4.0.0 with new site and new database. In Module Management we install "2sxc Content Management and App/Module Engine". If we add "Content" or "App" on a new page we receive an error "An Unexpected Error Has Occurred In ToSic.Sxc.Oqt.Content, ToSic.Sxc.Oqtane.Client: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".

Comment: We've done this many times without issues, so there must be something different in your setup. Can you provide more details? eg what does the Oqtane log say? Are you running it as F5 in Visual Studio or using IIS? Any special setup such as hosting on a NAS?

Comment: Someone had a similar issue and it was DB Security related - https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/3131#issuecomment-1634063786

Comment: The hint with the permissions in the database brought the solution. For security reasons I have not assigned the role "db_owner". That's why I've given permission for all stored procedures.
  USE OqtaneDb; GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::dbo TO [IIS APPPOOL\AppPoolOqtane];
My problem is solved. Thanks for the tip.